# Reflection of light wave in absence of colloids

Tags: visible-light

When light goes through air we see the Beam (if we are using a laser beam) because of dispersion by dust. I have two questions:

What happens in pure air or gases and what happens in pure water? **Why do we see the light if there is no dust?**

Any mathematical reasoning or link will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any irregularity in the path of the bundle will scatter light. Also the molecules constituting the medium, air water or glass, exhibit Rayleigh scattering. A very intense bundle will cause visible Rayleigh scattering. See also  [What makes some laser beams visible and other laser beams invisible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20259/what-makes-some-laser-beams-visible-and-other-laser-beams-invisible#20266)

For mathematical formulae check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering).

Comment: That's related to absortion of light in QM or is a different phenomena?

Comment: It is related. The scattering happens because the light polarises the molecules. Molecular polarisation is related to molecular quantum transitions, hence to absorption.