# What will happen if I will beam a ray of light in dark vaccum?

Tags: visible-light

My question is this what will happen if I will flash a beam of light just say in an dark area where nothing is present ( vaccum ) there to reflect light. Just say I am standing and someone flashed a light in front of me would I be able to see that light.( As there is no particle there to reflect light. )[image]

Comment: Related: [What makes some laser beams visible and other laser beams invisible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20259/21441)

Comment: Duplicate. [Why can we only “see” reflected light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325535/104696) and links therein.

Comment: One of my favorite science museum displays was a hole in a wall with a dark black space behind it. A sign above the hole asked, "Is there light inside? Stick your hand in the hole to find out." If you simply looked in the hole, you saw nothing but blackness, but if you put your hand (or any other object) through the hole, it would interrupt a bright-ish shaft of light that was shining down from above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would travel straight forward in form of energy (hidden), but as it strikes any object it would glow

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could see it only if the light ray when it directly reaches you from the source. Otherwise, provided the given conditions, one could not see light

Comment: You are saying I will not be able to see the light rather than it will be dark there although some flashed light.

Comment: Can you explain the phenomenon in more detail

Comment: You can see the light only when the beam reaches your eyes

Comment: As light always moves in straight lines. It will continue to move unless it is reflected by something. In the dark space there might be light... But the photons are not directed towards your eyes,but in another direction. Hence u can't see them